# How do I finish a reverse string?

Tags: java, string, reverse

So my teacher told me to make a string that makes whatever I type go in the opposite order
(e.g. "hello there" becomes "ereht olleh"). So far I worked on the body and I came up with this

```
   public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */     

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  (The input needs to be in here)}}



    public static String rev(String str) {

    String reversed = "hello there";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        reversed = str.charAt(i) + reversed;
    }
    return reversed;
```

My question now is that what I need to put under the **public static void main(String[] args)** to make it work. Yes I understand that this is homework, I tried looking through the book for help(no luck). I tried looking on the internet(no luck thanks to my little understanding to the more advanced method). I would appreciate any help and thank anyone in advance.
I use netbeans if that would help any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

Since you are adding the characters in reverse to the string `reversed` it should be an empty string to start with:

```
String reversed = "";
```

To call this method from `main` pass it the string that needs to be reversed. Something like:

```
public static void main(String...args[]) {
  System.out.println(rev("hello there"));
}
```

Alternatively you can read the string to be reversed as an input from the user and then pass it to the `rev` function.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static String rev(String str) {
  String reversed = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      reversed = str.charAt(i) + reversed;
  }
  return reversed;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(rev(args[0]));
  }
}
```

Read the args array to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make this as opaque as possible given the homework tag, you should, at a minimum, re-examine your initial value of `reversed`. The way you have it, you will end up with something other than the desired `"ereht olleh"`.

As to your specific question on how to get the arguments from the command line, the following prints out all the arguments and would form a good basis for your own code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        System.out.println (args[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read console input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String curLine = ""; // Line read from standard in
  System.out.println("Enter a line of text");
  InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
  curLine = in.readLine();

  System.out.println(rev(curLine));
}
```